# Angular2 does not render SVG in runtime

Tags: svg, angular

I am trying to render SVG graphics in run-time with no success. Only works if i put the SVG code inside the component's template.

I have tried it using the *ComponentFactoryResolver* and the ViewContainerRef's method *createComponent*. After that, the *Renderer* class (i'm trying to not use the *nativeElement* due the recommendations from Angular team), adding the namespace before the tagname: `<svg:rect>` and the selector property `selector: ':svg:g[svg-box]'`...

I am using Angular 2.0.0-rc.5. You can check it here https://plnkr.co/edit/HsqyQgFGwiIVVJIPu31k?p=preview

In both cases the generated HTML code is correct but it doesn't render anything.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it!!

Using the *Renderer* class, when we create SVG elements we have to add the following before the element's tag: `:svg:tag`. In my case:

```
this.SVGRenderer.createElement(this.parent.nativeElement, ":svg:rect");
```

You can check it in this plunker's version 3: https://plnkr.co/edit/HsqyQgFGwiIVVJIPu31k?p=preview

Now i'm trying to do the same using the *ComponentFactoryResolver* and the ViewContainerRef's method *createComponent* approach.

Comment: What is the class "SVGRenderer" please?

Comment: could you achieve this with `ComponentFactoryResolver` ? Angular seems to have a bug. it just does not render